# Underscores Theme Architecture

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, themes

I'm sort of new to WordPress and using stripped down WordPress themes. I recently started using underscores. So far its great and I will definitely continue to use it. I would just like to understand it better so I can use it correctly.

One thing that confuses me is the architecture of the theme. All of the templates that are created be default with underscores call to template parts which are located in the template part folder.

I've seen other themes that use this method as well. My question is why is it better to set up the site architecture in this way as opposed to just creating the template by itself with out using template parts? My thinking is the more parts there are the more confusing the site is and the harder it is to debug. There must be a reason if so many sites use this type of architecture.

Comment: Check [Understanding Wordpress theme files and underscores](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/221907/12615) and [Highest Voted 'theme-development' Questions - WordPress Development Stack Exchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/theme-development?sort=votes&pageSize=50)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you separate your code in "template-parts" (in this case) you can re-use it and if you need to change something on it, you just need to change it once (instead of all the places you used it).

Break your code in smaller and independent parts to make it easier to maintain and to reuse.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense I actually just came to this conclusion a few minutes ago with one of my co workers. I guess the reason I didnt come to this realization sooner is that the work we do doesn't call for the components to be used in different places. Our sites, basically only use two page layouts. One for the home page one for "interior" pages. So this doesn't benefit our builds very much. Thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: Yeah, not all the projects need the same structure. But it's a good habit to get.
Good luck on your project!